# How to programmatically binding width DataGridColumn from another DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to programmatically binding the width of a column from one table to the width of a column in another table. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
DataGridTextColumn classNameColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
classNameColumn.Header = "CLASS";
classNameColumn.Binding = new Binding("CLASS_NAME");
classNameColumn.IsReadOnly = true;
ScheduleGrid.Columns.Add(classNameColumn);

DataGridTextColumn noneColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
noneColumn.Header = "";
var bindingWidth = new Binding("Width") { Source = classNameColumn, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(noneColumn, WidthProperty, bindingWidth);
WeeekHeaderGrid.Columns.Add(noneColumn);
```

In XAML-code this work fine:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="ScheduleGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
              CellEditEnding="ScheduleGrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ClassName" Header="CLASS" Binding="{Binding CLASS_NAME}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="WeeekHeaderGrid" Grid.Row="0" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference ClassName}, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "In XAML-code this work fine:" -- So...

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm trying to make creating table columns using a cycle in C# code. XAML-solution does not suit me

Comment: @EdPlunkett, it is guaranteed that there is equivalent c# code for given xaml markup, but that c# implementation is not obvious sometimes

Comment: @ASh True. But it’s usually a better idea to do it in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using incorrect `WidthProperty` DP in code.

change it to

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(noneColumn, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, bindingWidth);
```

`DataGridColumn.WidthProperty` has type `DataGridLength`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=ClassName, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

That should working.

Comment: My XAML-solution also work. But it does not suit me. I'm trying to make creating table columns using a cycle in C# code.