# Binding to Properties not work in CodeBehind but work in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I needed to make the columns in different Grids move dependently on each other. I found a good solution:

1. In the properties create value
   [image]
2. In the xamlI create a binding:

```
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition 
        Width="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=GridColumnWidth,
        Converter={StaticResource ColumnWidthConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        MinWidth="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="50"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

3. And implement converter:

```
public class ColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string str && !str.Equals("*"))
            return new GridLength(double.Parse(str));
        return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is GridLength gridLength)
            return gridLength.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return "*";
    }
}
```

Now I needed to do the same in CodeBehind. I do this:

```
ColumnDefinition propertyNameColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
propertyNameColumnDefinition.MinWidth = 50;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(propertyNameColumnDefinition, WidthProperty, CreateBindingForColumnWidth());
ColumnDefinition gridSplitterColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto };
ColumnDefinition propertyValueColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
propertyValueColumnDefinition.MinWidth = 50;
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(headerRowDefinition);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(propertyNameColumnDefinition);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridSplitterColumnDefinition);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(propertyValueColumnDefinition);
.......
private Binding CreateBindingForColumnWidth()
{
    Binding b = new Binding
    {
        Source = mpESKD.Properties.Settings.Default,
        Path = new PropertyPath("GridColumnWidth"),
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
        Converter = new ColumnWidthConverter()
    };
    return b;
}
```

In this case, nothing works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check which `WidthProperty` is used. try `ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty`. see [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378890/1506454)

Comment: is converter method triggered, and if yes which value it receives?

Comment: ASh, Thank! Excellent observation and correct assumption

Answer (score 0):

Must be:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(propertyNameColumnDefinition, ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, CreateBindingForColumnWidth());
```

Thank for **ASh** for his comment